# Why didn't the Separatist leaders look surprised about Jango Fett?

Tags: star-wars

I was hoping for some clarification as to why Nute Gunray especially did not question the fact that Jango Fett, the key clone template of his enemy's army (the Republic) was standing **right next to him** in the Geonosian battle arena, and not so much as a simple comment on this fact is made to Dooku or to anyone else. And no comment is made during the whole period of the clone wars- to my knowledge.

It is very, very puzzling! Hope some closure can be made on this

Comment: Who knew he was the template for the clones, other than the ones who arranged it (Dooku & Sidious), and the Jedi who discovered it?

Comment: @Adeptus: anyone who saw both Jango and a trooper without their helmets?

Comment: Nute isn't human. Who's to say that he can even tell us apart?

Comment: @Richard Hahaha intergalactic racism at its finest! :p

Comment: Doesn't mean it isn't plausible.  If the Asians think all Caucasians look the same;  isn't it feasible to suggest Nemoidians think everyone else looks the same?

Comment: Is there a canon source proving that Nute even knows who Jango is, or even that there is a clone army being made? For all he knows it can be a random body guard.

Comment: @Coco - it has nothing to do with racism. It's how species evolve. Pattern recognition is EXPENSIVE, so you fine tune it to things you need (your close kin)

Answer (score 9):

Nute Gunray was not even aware of the existence of the Grand Army of the Republic (much less the fact that the troopers were clones) until the [Battle of Geonosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Geonosis):

> Many Jedi were killed before Jedi Grand Master Yoda arrived with clone troopers from Kamino, **an army that had been secretly created for the Republic**.

The clone troopers' helmets hide their faces so even if Gunray and the other Separatist leaders had seen a clone trooper beforehand they would not have known that Jango was the clones' template. [Jango had originally been hired by Count Dooku to be the clones' template](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jango_Fett/Canon), but obviously Dooku's involvement in the creation of the Grand Army was hidden from the Separatist leaders (otherwise the Separatist leaders would not have trusted or worked with Dooku).

Moreover, **Jango Fett had actually worked as a bounty hunter for the Separatists**. He was [hired by Dooku to assassinate Senator Amidala because Gunray wanted her dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74360/31936). The entire reason the Jedi found Kamino and learned of the Grand Army was due to Jango's involvement in this assassination attempt: Obi-Wan tracked Jango to Kamino from the [Kamino saberdart](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino_saberdart/Canon) he used to kill [Zam Wesell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zam_Wesell/Canon) after she was captured by the Jedi so that she could not reveal his involvement in the assassination attempt.

Comment: Specifically, Jango worked directly for Dooku. The attempt on Amidala's life was a concession - essentially a "gift" from Dooku to Nute Gunray. The entire reason Fett sub-contracted Zam to do the job instead of doing it himself was so that it didn't lead back to Dooku. His mistake was using Kaminoan technology to silence Zam, but at the time he was in a bit of a pinch.

Comment: @Omegacron Yes, thanks. I had made the connection between Fett-Dooku-Gunray in a different answer, which I've now linked to.

Answer (score 8):

At that point in time, Nute had never seen a clone, or even knew the clones existed.  He had no idea what the clones looked like.  Their arrival was a complete surprise to him.  Only Dooku and Sidious knew about the clone army.  And Jango was associated with Dooku, so Nute would have had no cause or reason to be concerned or question Jango's presence.

Comment: This post could be improved with canon citations...