# Why use centipedes to assassinate Padmé?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Why did they try to kill Padmé with centipedes, when the droid could have just shot her once it had cut the window?

Is there any explanation beyond shoddy writing?

Comment: My guess. If the two Jedi weren't around, the centipedes would have killed Padme and the bounty hunter would have been long gone before anybody even knew.

Comment: @DeeV makes sense if they hadn't tried to blow up her ship. I don't think subtlety was key

Comment: Because they didn't want Padme dead. Padme is vital for Sith plan (Anakin's fall to dark side, and Jedi discovery of Kamino and Clone troopers)

Comment: @rs.29 - You seem to be pushing this theory very hard. Have you got anything to back it up?

Comment: @Valorum Cui bono ;) Look what man behind it all does. And that man is Palpatine. Watch Attack of the Clones very carefully. Especially the part where he practically pushes Anakin and Padme together ;)

Comment: @rs.29 - I don't disagree that Palpatine's all about the "plans within plans" but I think you're crediting him with omniscience.

Comment: Or Jango Fett could have just blown up Padme's apartment with a bomb. But death by poisonous centipede is less(?) suspicious, especially if the centipedes had not been detected.

Comment: @Valorum Palpatine is master of deception. Remember, he looks like weak old man, outside he is ardent supporter of Republic, in RoTJ he even allowed that plans of DS2 fall in Rebel hands. In Return of the Sith he purposely told Anakin he was Sith Lord in order to lure Windu and others to attack him, therefore creating legal reason for Order 66 and declaration of Empire.

Comment: @rs.29 - I think the problem here is that you're mixing stuff that's genuinely canon (e.g. backed up by the films, novels, etc) with stuff that's headcanon (e.g. pure fan-theory).

Comment: @RobertF Since there was an assassination attempt on Amidala very recently relative to the kouhun attack, if she were to die it would be seen as an assassination even if the killer escaped and left no evidence.  No one's going to think it was natural causes, especially considering that she was young and had no health problems.

Comment: @Valorum It may be true that what rs.29 says isn't pure canon, but those examples plus the Force certainly make the idea much less of a leap in logic. Palpatine does seem to have a way of playing the long game and for his elaborate scheming to end mostly as he intended. The only foul up I can think of that had any long lasting impact on his plans is not anticipating Vader's final betrayal. (Yes, that one mistake cost him dearly.)

Comment: @jpmc26 - My issue here is that that these "Jango is intentionally leading the Jedi / Palpatine knows that Jango will lead the JedI" fan-theories contradict both the script and the novels. I could understand if it was vague, but it's not.

Comment: @rs.29, Valorum: this comment conversation was getting very long, so I've [moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56785/discussion-on-question-by-doctor-two-why-use-centipedes-to-assassinate-padme) - please continue the discussion there instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jango thinks they're **more subtle.**

> *If Jango was having any similar thoughts about her, his helmet hid
> them. **“We’ll have to try something more subtle this time, Zam,”** he
> said without preamble as soon as she was close enough. “My client is
> getting impatient.”
>
> I’ll bet, Zam thought, but she only nodded.
>
> “There can be no mistakes this time,” the other bounty hunter went on. “Take > these. Be careful. They’re very poisonous.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

The Databank indicates that **their venom is especially deadly to humans**

> Their venom is particularly deadly to humanoid species, which is why
> Jango Fett gave a pair of them to Zam Wessel in their attempt to
> assassinate Senator Padme Amidala.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Databank: **Kouhun**](http://www.starwars.com/databank/kouhun)</sup></sub>

---

They're **untraceable and can evade security**

[image]

> <sub><sup>"Zam uses two deadly kouhuns for her Senatorial assassination
> Job. **Small, silent arthropods like the kouhuns of Indoumodo can evade
> even tight security. Unlike projectiles or energy weapons, they are
> virtually impossible to trace back to their users.** Kouhuns are starved
> in advance, so they head straight for warm-blooded life forms when
> released, and use a fast-acting nerve toxin to kill their prey."</sup></sub>
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

---

They're **very reliable, very deadly and able to evade the most sophisticated surveillance equipment**

> Kouhuns actuolly have two separate toxin-delivery systems. **The stinger
> on the end of their foil can deliver an excruciating venom that leaves
> the victim writhing in agony. Although this is not fatal, it allows
> the kouhun to employ its mandibles. These release a fast-acting toxin
> that can kill large animals in seconds**. For those who have already
> been stung by the tail, the end comes as a welcome reprieve from the
> pain.
>
> Another reason **kouhuns are favoured by assassins is that they are
> expert stealth hunters. They are able to bypass the most sophisticated
> / security systems  with an almost Force-sensitive awareness.** The pair
> of kouhuns that almost killed Senator Amidala, for example, managed to
> scurry just a short distance in front of an astromech droid programmed
> to be on alert. If it had not been for the two Jedi standing guard
> outside the room, the kouhuns would surely have feasted on Naboo flesh
> that night.
>
> Luckily for the Senator, kouhuns instinctively strike at the neck,
> even though a jab to a toe would be just as fatal. The time the
> kouhuns took to scurry up Amidala's body to her neck gave the guardian
> Jedi just long enough to kill the creatures. Even so, Amidala knew
> that she had stared death in the face.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Fact File Vol 1. #124](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_124)</sup></sub>

It's noted that t**heir behavious is highly predictable and, because of their sheer rarity, largely untraceable.**

> A small group of bounty hunters, including Jango Fett, were aware of a
> creature, native to the planet Indoumodo, that could be used as the
> perfect weapon. Kouhuns are sizeable carnivorous arthropods that use
> their lethal nerve toxin to fell larger animals and consume their
> flesh. **When hungry, kouhuns become entirely one-track-minded and will
> head for the first organic form. This makes them highly useful for
> assassins, as they behave almost as predictably as a droid - but
> without the disadvantage of being traceable.**
>
> Assassins are always looking for new ways to dispose of their targets.
> **The best methods allow for long-distance application and cannot be
> traced back to the user. With modern forensic science, it is possible
> to trace bullets, bomb debris and even blaster scorch marks back to
> the owners of the weapons. Other weapons, such as vibroblades and more
> primitive devices, require the assassin to get very close to the
> target.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Fact File Vol 1. #124](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_124)</sup></sub>

You may wish to note that this *supposed* 'security through obscurity' is the same reason that Jango used a Kamino Saberdart instead of a more conventional weapon.

Comment: So they think that assassinating someone with a weapon that only a few people are known to use makes them *harder* to trace?

Comment: My theory is that they were supposed to draw attention, and not kill Padme. She got Jedi bodyguards after the first attempt. Those bugs are living beings, and as such, can be sensed through the Force. Padme could be defended against them, as opposed to a blaster rifle or another bomb, or anything "instant". That way the Jedi took the bait, started the chase, were led to Kamino, then Geonosis, allowing the Clone Wars to start - which is what Jango's employers were aiming for.

Comment: @Petersaber - Come and join us in the headcanon dooku/palpatine chatroom so that you may become enlightened about how wrong you are; http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56686/discussion-on-answer-by-werrf-did-tyranus-know-that-the-clones-would-be-at-the-b

Comment: @Ray - Damn good question. Apparently so.

Comment: "If it had not been for the two Jedi standing guard outside the room, the kouhuns would surely have feasted on Naboo flesh that night." Well, that answers the question that was rattling around in my brain -- as to why centipedes would have such specialization for killing large mammals in the first place. Apparently that's the most convenient prey for them that their environment could come up with. Just imagine those fearsome mandibles ripping the flesh from your bones! :-P (I honestly thought they were unnecessarily fancy robotic drones when I first saw the scene, shows how wrong I was...)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - It also explains why Zam used a droid. She wasn't keen to tangle with Jedi (according to the novelisation).

Comment: @jpmc26 - I heartily agree that Palpatine's plan works out, but that's due to the robustness of the plan (that it can survive being brought forward as a result of Jango's ineptitude and the surprisingly effective Jedi investigation) rather than it being what he originally had in mind.

Comment: @Valorum Kindly explain what would happen if Zam (or Fett) managed to kill Padme. How would that help Sith to achieve their long term plans ?

Comment: @rs.29 - The Sith weren't paying for the 'hit'. The text of the novel(s) make it clear that [it was the Trade Federation that were trying to kill her](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74352/why-did-the-separatists-want-to-kill-padm%C3%A9), albeit they later turn to Dooku after their initial attempts fail.My guess is that Palpatine either couldn't have cared less (given Padmé's known anti-war tendencies) or positively wanted her dead due to her opposition to the act to create an army.

Comment: @Valorum Palpatine -> Dooku -> Gunray . Palpatine wanted her dead so bad he sent Chosen One to protect her :)  Dooku arranged contract with Fett, therefore Palpatine certainly knew about it. From Palpatine´s point of view, best outcome is not Padme dead, but Padme distracted and Anakin and her falling in love. And that is exactly what happened.

Comment: @rs.29 - Except that Dooku didn't care less about Anakin and tried to have him killed in the arena and Palpatine sees Anakin as more of a long-term asset. One that might not pay off.

Comment: @rs.29 - Don't forget that the whole "Anakin becomes his new apprentice" plotline is a secondary plan as far as Palpatine is concerned. His main interest is in creating a war and killing all the Jedi.